# Find all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ satisfying the given inequality: $|z - 5| + |z + 1| \leq |z - 2|$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

> I'd like to find all points $z \in \mathbb{C}$ which satisfy this inequality
> $$
> |z-5|+|z+1| \leq |z-2|. 
> $$

I have tried this multiple times and I keep getting stuck.
I start off with:
$$
|x-5+iy|+|x+1+iy| \leq |x-2+iy|
$$
$$
\sqrt{(x-5)^2+y^2} + \sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2} \leq \sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2}
$$
Then do not know what to do from here

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Could you tell us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Show your work. A good start would be to determine the boundary curve with an $=$ rather than the inequality $\leq$.

Comment: $|a|+|b|\geq|a+b|.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the inequality into two weaker inequalities:

$$
\begin{aligned}
|z-5| &\leq |z-2| \\
|z+1| &\leq |z-2|
\end{aligned}
$$

The first requires $\Re(z)\geq 3.5$ while the second requires $\Re(z)\leq 0.5$ so obviously no $z$ fulfil both simultaneously

Answer (score 1):

Let $w = z - 2$. Then the proposed inequality is equivalent to:
\begin{align*}
|z - 5| + |z + 1| \leq |z - 2| & \Longleftrightarrow |w - 3| + |w + 3| \leq |w|
\end{align*}
where the latter inequality is never true. Indeed, according to the triangle inequality, one has that:
\begin{align*}
|w - 3| + |w + 3| \geq |(w - 3) + (w + 3)| = 2|w| \geq |w| \geq 0
\end{align*}
where the equality holds only when $w = 0$.

But we if we substitute back the value $w = 0$, it yields that $6 \leq 0$, which is clearly false.

Hence the proposed claim holds.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: You mean to say that $z=2$ is a solution which implies $6 \le 0$!

Answer (score 0):

The other responses are best, for this particular problem.  However, it is also important to know the general method for attacking this type of problem.  That way, you will be able to routinely identify the solution set, when the inequality does have solutions.

Alternative approach:

For $~z \in \Bbb{C},~$ assume $~z = (x + iy) ~: ~x,y \in \Bbb{R}.$

Note that for any $~u,v \in \Bbb{R},~$ you have that

$$w = u + iv \implies |w| = \sqrt{u^2 + v^2}. \tag1 $$

So, all that you have to do is (if all else fails) dispense with elegance, apply the formula in (1) above, and see where it leads.  I will use the specific problem to elaborate.

The constraint is that

$$|z-5|+|z+1| \leq |z-2|. $$

As the analysis in the presented problem indicated, this implies that

$$|(x-5) + iy| + |(x+1) + iy| \leq |(x-2) + iy|. \tag2 $$

To attack this problem (or other problems of this type), you are trying to determine the necessary relationship between $~x~$ and $~y,~$ for all satisfying values of $z$, if any.

Using the definition in (1) above, the constraint represented by (2) above may be equivalently presented as

$$\sqrt{(x-5)^2 + y^2} + \sqrt{(x+1)^2 + y^2} \leq \sqrt{(x-2)^2 + y^2}. \tag3 $$

---

The standard approach to attacking a constraint represented by (3) above is to square both sides.  However, before you do, you have to $\color{red}{\text{stop and think}}$ about what you are doing.

Suppose that you have a constraint that looks like

$r \leq s.$  
This does not (normally) imply that $~\displaystyle r^2 \leq s^2.$

For example, $-4 \leq 1$, but $(-4)^2$ is not less than or equal to $(1)^2.$

However, the constraint represented by (3) above is different.  By convention the expression $~\sqrt{x}~$ always represents a non-negative value.  This means that you are **guaranteed** that both sides of the inequality in (3) above are non-negative.

When you have that $0 \leq r \leq s$, 
this **will** imply that $r^2 \leq s^2.$

So, consider the following alteration of the constraint in (3), which is created by squaring both sides of (3):

$$\left[ ~(x-5)^2 + y^2 ~\right] + \left[ ~(x+1)^2 + y^2 ~\right] \\
+ 2\sqrt{(x-5)^2 + y^2}\sqrt{(x+1)^2 + y^2} \\ \leq \left[ ~(x-2)^2 + y^2 ~\right]. \tag4 $$

From the previous discussion, you know that given any $~z = x+ iy, ~z~$ will satisfy the constraint in (3) above if and only if $~z~$ satisfies the constraint in (4) above.

So, the entire problem has been reduced to attacking the constraint in (4) above.

---

Expanding the terms gives:

$$(x^2 - 10x + 25) + y^2 + (x^2 + 2x + 1) + y^2\\
+ 2\sqrt{(x-5)^2 + y^2}\sqrt{(x+1)^2 + y^2}\\
\leq (x^2 - 4x + 4).$$

Combining the expanded terms and subtracting the RHS from the LHS gives:

$$(x^2 - 4x + 22) + y^2 \\ + 2\sqrt{(x-5)^2 + y^2}\sqrt{(x+1)^2 + y^2} \\ \leq 0. \tag5 $$

So, a complex number $~z = (x + iy)~$ will satisfy the constraint in (2) above if and only if it's real and imaginary components, $~x~$ and $~y,~$ satisfy the constraint in (5) above.

For similar problems, you will often reach an intermediate constraint, similar to the one expressed in (5) above.  In such a circumstance, you will then be wondering what to do next.

One approach is to then isolate the radical.  In the present problem, this would be done by re-expressing the constraint in (5) to:

$$(x^2 - 4x + 22) + y^2 \\ \leq -2\sqrt{(x-5)^2 + y^2}\sqrt{(x+1)^2 + y^2}. \tag6 $$

You would then **consider** attacking (6) above by squaring both sides.  However, you would (again) have to be very careful to first consider whether squaring both sides is valid.

Further, even if it is valid, you have to consider that the result will be an inequality that involves a **fourth degree** polynomial.  Math problem composers don't normally oppress their students with this type of difficulty.

That is because the problem composers usually intend that the problem will be an application of recently taught theory.  There isn't normally any educational value in asking a student to struggle with a fourth degree polynomial.

In the present problem, assuming that you reach the point in (6) above, that is avoidable.  You can complete the square on the LHS to convert the constraint into:

$$(x-2)^2 + 18 + y^2 \\
\leq -2\sqrt{(x-5)^2 + y^2}\sqrt{(x+1)^2 + y^2}. \tag7 $$

You can now reason that (7) above has no solutions, because the LHS must be positive and the right hand side must be non-positive.

You can not have a positive number be less than or equal to a non-positive number.

---

So, now that you have seen the (very inelegant) more general method of attack, you have to wonder: what was the intent of the problem composer?

Personally, I suspect that the problem composer did **not** intend that the method employed in my answer be used.  This is because if the composer had such an intent, he would probably have assigned a problem that does have some satisfying complex numbers $~z.$

Further, as another response has indicated, the problem can be routinely resolved by noting that

$$|z| + |w| \geq |z + w|.$$

So, the problem composer probably intended that the problem be an application of the above inequality.  However, the original poster's attempt to *go back to basics* was perfectly viable (and valid).  There is no reason why such an approach can not be used to resolve the problem.

That is the point of my response.